# Eclipse Helios not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

I recently upgraded from Eclipse Galileo to Helios. Helios stops at breakpoints ONLY when debugging "as a PHP Script", but not when debugging "as a Web Page".

When debugging as a web page, it looks like the correct debug query string to start a debug session is getting tacked on to the url, like so:

`http://localhost/hello.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP &KEY=129798139020511`

but elipse does not stop at the breakpoints. It just zooms thru the code and displays the output in the browser.

This is my xdebug configuration in php.ini that works for Galileo, but is not working for Helios: (click [here](http://noodleworx.com/public/xdebug_config.gif) to see my entire xdebug config settings)

```
;extension=xdebug.so <-- is this needed?
zend_extension=" /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-no n-zts-20090626/xdebug.so "
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=

; to enable remote debugging
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1/32
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

Can you post your xdebug configuration that works for Helios? If possible, can you share the xdebug portion of your phpinfo() output? Would like to compare settings of an xdebug configuration that works on Helios with what I have.

Comment: Is it related to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=306834 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the exact same issue.  I did find some bug reports about breakpoints in Galileo not being able to be used in Helios.  I can get Helios to stop on breakpoints at times, but I have to delete all my breakpoints and then start debugging, and only after that add a breakpoint.  Needless to say this is very annoying.  I'll try and find the link that I saw and add it to here.

For now I've gone back to Galileo.

Malks.

Comment: This bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312951 seems to be closer to it.

Comment: I've gone back to Galileo, too :(

Comment: Is debugging "as a Web Page" actually works in Eclipse Galileo? Though you posted this question over two years ago, even now (May 2013) I found that Helios doesn't stops on breakpoints when using Xdebug. Following your advice I also switched from Helios to Galileo, but found no difference. Galileo also doesn't stops on breakpoints!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits
- Eclipse Luna
- Nginx
- PHP Fpm (via socket)

I solved this debugging problem disabling IPV6

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the following lines:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then reboot or `sudo sysctl -p`