# XDebug / Apache / PHP / Eclipse skips breakpoints

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm having problems with XDebug.

Configuration as follows:

- Windows 7 64bit
- PHP 5.4.6 Thread Safe 32 bit
- Apache 2.4 Thread Safe
- Eclipse PDT 3.0.2

The problem is that xdebug_break() calls are not working, and breakpoints entered through Eclipse also don't function. I can see that the extension is working, as it appears as a module in phpinfo(). When I call an uncallable method, XDebug outputs the relevant error messages.

I've modified Eclipse's web server path mapping, to no avail.

Here is my php.ini config:

```
zend_extension = c:/php/php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 8080
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated...

Comment: *cough* netbeans *cough*

Answer (score 1):

First check that what version you are using of PHP in eclipse....
Check it through:
**Window->preference->PHP->PHP Interpreter....**

Version there should match with the PHP version.....

Reply if problem is not solved....

Answer (score 1):

For all those, that are still fighting with this problem, some handy tips.

Check which version (package) of Eclipse you have? It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5035964/1469208), that Helios package has some bugs and doesn't stops on breakpoints, when you debug your application as `Web Application`. Debugging works only, if you run it as `PHP Script`. Which makes it pretty useless for debugging process.

You should consider either reverting to older [Galileo Package Eclipse for PHP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/galileosr2) or installing newest [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-422/junosr2) (or even [newest developer version of Eclipse Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-43-m7/keplerm7)), which doesn't have PDT support build in, but you can easily add it to then, using `Help > Install New Software..` (point it to `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release`).

These versions are reported to be able to debug as `Web Application`, respecting breakpoints.

Also, remember, that Xdebug must be run as *Zend Extension* in order to support breakpoints! In other words remove `extension=xdebug.so` (on Linux or `xdebug.dll` on Windows) line from your `php.ini` and replace it with `zend_extension=/full/path/to/xdebug.so` (on Linux or `zend_extension=X:\full\path\to\xdebug.dll` on Windows). Zend extensions requires full path, even if they're put into `/php/ext` folder, as regular PHP extensions. You'll find more info on this in [Xdebug FAQ](http://xdebug.org/docs/faq) (look for an answer to "*Xdebug is only loaded as PHP extension and not as a Zend Extension*" question).