# Can not make PHP PDT xDebug to stop at breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

By choosing Break at First line, the debugger gets active when entering each file, allowing me to step in and out of the code.
But it is a bit cumbersome having to tab your way through half a million steps to get to the point where it starts to get interesting.

My setup is WIMP Window 7, PHP 5.3

```
; xDebug config
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9-nts.dll"

xdebug.remote_autostart=0;
xdebug.remote_enable=On 
xdebug.remote_host="localhost" 
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

I have made sure that the path mapping is correct.
But could it be because i'm linking to the PHP files from my Eclipse project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading **Eclipse Juno** i'm able to stop at breakpoints.

I have tried everything with Eclipse Indigo.
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800

Just wont work, either with an internal or external browser.

Time to move on to Juno i guess?

Comment: Oh no !! I'm having the same problem even with Eclipse Juno !! Debugger stops at the first line when "Break at First Line" is checked but not stopping at the line where I set breakpoint after un-checking "Break at First Line". Here is my [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092105/php-wamp-exlipse-pdt-xdebug-not-stopping-at-breakpoint), can you plz check my settings and tell me what I've done wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse has an option to turn off "break at first line". Go to "Windows -> Preferences -> PHP -> Debug" and uncheck "Break at first line" and also to go in "Run > Debug Configurations > PHP Web Application" and unselect "Break at first line" in all the configurations. Then restart Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Derick. I have tried that. Since yesterday i also tried to install Zend. Same problem. The debugger just whizzed through the breakpoints, but stopped at first line when enabled

Comment: The very first sentence in the question makes crystal clear that he knows about that option.

Answer (score -1):

For all those, that are still fighting with this problem, some handy tips.

Check which version (package) of Eclipse you have? It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5035964/1469208), that Helios package has some bugs and doesn't stops on breakpoints, when you debug your application as `Web Application`. Debugging works only, if you run it as `PHP Script`. Which makes it pretty useless for debugging process.

You should consider either reverting to older [Galileo Package Eclipse for PHP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/galileosr2) or installing newest [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-422/junosr2) (or even [newest developer version of Eclipse Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-43-m7/keplerm7)), which doesn't have PDT support build in, but you can easily add it to then, using `Help > Install New Software..` (point it to `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release`).

These versions are reported to be able to debug as `Web Application`, respecting breakpoints.

Also, remember, that Xdebug must be run as *Zend Extension* in order to support breakpoints! In other words remove `extension=xdebug.so` (on Linux or `xdebug.dll` on Windows) line from your `php.ini` and replace it with `zend_extension=/full/path/to/xdebug.so` (on Linux or `zend_extension=X:\full\path\to\xdebug.dll` on Windows). Zend extensions requires full path, even if they're put into `/php/ext` folder, as regular PHP extensions. You'll find more info on this in [Xdebug FAQ](http://xdebug.org/docs/faq) (look for an answer to "*Xdebug is only loaded as PHP extension and not as a Zend Extension*" question).

Comment: I followed "Xdebug must be run as Zend Extension" comment.
And then used FireFox (instead of Chrome/internal browser). I think the last step was the one that fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a post describing how to get breakpoints to work with XDebug in Eclipse.

http://programmersjunk.blogspot.com/2013/05/eclipse-and-xdebug.html

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.