# PHP (WAMP) - Exlipse PDT, xDebug: not stopping at breakpoint

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am able to debug only if I check the Option **"Break at First line"**. If I un-check it and place a breakpoint at some line then the debugger doesn't stop at that line.

**I need the debugger to stop at the breakpoints I set, not at the fist line of the file.**

I've added the following lines in my php.ini file:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

I'm also being able to debug properly on **Notepad++ DBGp debugger** with this same setting.

There are similar posts on SO but none solves my problem. In SO question ["Can not make PHP PDT xDebug to stop at breakpoints in Eclipse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522671/can-not-make-php-pdt-xdebug-to-stop-at-breakpoints-in-eclipse), [DevNull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869779/devnull) says the problem was solved for Juno, but I'm using Juno myself and having the problem.

Here are some screenshots of my Eclipse settings:

**Window --> Preferences --> PHP --> Debug:**
[image]

**Window --> Preferences --> PHP --> PHP Executables:**
[image]

**Window --> Preferences --> PHP --> PHP Executables --> Execution Environment:**
[image]

**Window --> Preferences --> PHP --> PHP Interpreters:**

[image]

**Window --> Preferences --> PHP --> PHP Servers:**
[image]

I'm using Mozilla Firefox as my external web browser. (**Window --> General --> Web Browser**)

The Project **Debug Configuration --> PHP Web Application --> Debugger --> Server Debugger** is set to **XDebug** and XDebug debug port is set to `9000`

Hope those will help someone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you should try to upgrade xdebug version?

Also how did you installed Juno? Just clean install or update?

Try clean install in another folder and copy you workspace settings. Or try without them.

Comment: I'm using the xDebug that came with my wamp installation (in my `"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\zend_ext"` directory). I also tried with the newer version of xDebug downloaded using [xDebug Wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php), but this doesn't work, doesn't even stop at the first line of the file while debugging. And I had installed Eclipse Juno after directly downloading from [Eclipse Download Page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: @HeartBeat try to use clean workspace settings. File / Workspace / Switch other ...
May be some settings was incorrect somewhere.

Comment: Also try just phpinfo() and check all settings under xdebug -- may be some of them incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512307/xampp-1-7-3-eclipse-pdt-xdebug-debugging-a-php-web-page-in-eclipse-never-st?rq=1

Comment: Thanks gaRex , I've re-installed WAMP and xDebug, changed the php.ini file accordingly and switched Eclipse Workspace, now it's working. I think the problem was in some of my Eclipse Settings.

Comment: I had a random breaking of breakpoints in PDT/xdebug that was fixed by just recreating my workspace.

Answer (score 3):

For those that accepted solution doesn't work:

Check xdebug setting: `xdebug.remote_enable`. Must be **ON**
(Go to *phpinfo()* to see current setting).
Reference [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug)

Comment: In my question, I did mention that I had set `xdebug.remote_enable = on`. So, the problem was not because of this.